# MySQL: Automate this chain of queries (new columns from values)

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table that contains data which looks like this:

```
date          met       val

2012-10-18    avgt    63.3617
2012-10-16    avgt    65.7312
2012-10-19    avgt    66.4952
2012-10-17    avgt    67.3747
2012-10-18    cdd     53.3617
2012-10-17    cdd     55.3472
2012-10-19    cdd     66.8063
2012-10-16    cdd     67.3116
2012-10-18    maxt    43.3617
2012-10-19    maxt    47.4484
2012-10-16    maxt    65.9559
2012-10-17    maxt    66.2868
2012-10-19    mint    56.0447
2012-10-16    mint    65.0656
2012-10-18    mint    65.0656
2012-10-17    mint    66.4952
```

The **met** column has only 4 possible values (avgt,mint,maxt,cdd,hdd) which label the data in the **val** column. I need a query (probably a stored procedure) that would ***rearrange the data to look like this:***

```
 date           avgt        cdd         maxt        mint
 2012-10-16     65.7312     67.3116     65.9559     65.0656 
 2012-10-17     67.3747     55.3472     66.2868     66.4952 
 2012-10-18     63.3617     53.3617     43.3617     65.0656 
 2012-10-19     56.0447     66.8063     47.4484     56.0447
```

To do this in a static manner is easy. But I want this to be done dynamically, *such that the rearrangement properly occurs not matter what the values in the `met` column actually are*.

#### Here is how I would do this manually:

Add the additional columns:

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE  
ADD COLUMN  avgt FLOAT( 15, 5 ) NOT NULL AFTER  val , 
ADD COLUMN  mint FLOAT( 15, 5 ) NOT NULL AFTER  avgt , 
ADD COLUMN  maxt FLOAT( 15, 5 ) NOT NULL AFTER  mint , 
ADD COLUMN  cdd  FLOAT( 15, 5 ) NOT NULL AFTER  hdd
```

Update the new columns at each row:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET avgt = val WHERE metric == 'avgt';
SET mint = val WHERE metric == 'mint';
SET maxt = val WHERE metric == 'maxt';
SET cdd  = val WHERE metric == 'cdd';
```

Drop the old columns

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE
DROP COLUMN met,
DROP COLUMN val;
```

I understand how to get the list of unique `met` values as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT met FROM MYTABLE
```

What I am lacking in the logic in between. I need to iterate through the distinct values. If someone could help me out with that I would greatly appreciate it.

I will accept an answer written in pure SQL (probably stored procedure), or in Python.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: "But I want this to be done dynamically, such that the rearrangement properly occurs not matter what the values in the met column actually are." - Do you mean that the original 4 values used in 'met' might change to become more than 4 possible values and/or different possible values?

Comment: @PinnyM Yes, that is correct. Or the names may change.

Answer (score 1):

As you need a flexible solution which doesn't rely on values in met column best way would be to do it in python, after getting data from database e.g.

```
data_str = """2012-10-18    avgt    63.3617
2012-10-16    avgt    65.7312
2012-10-19    avgt    66.4952
2012-10-17    avgt    67.3747
2012-10-18    cdd     53.3617
2012-10-17    cdd     55.3472
2012-10-19    cdd     66.8063
2012-10-16    cdd     67.3116
2012-10-18    maxt    43.3617
2012-10-19    maxt    47.4484
2012-10-16    maxt    65.9559
2012-10-17    maxt    66.2868
2012-10-19    mint    56.0447
2012-10-16    mint    65.0656
2012-10-18    mint    65.0656
2012-10-17    mint    66.4952"""

data = []
# convert to array data as it would be from sql
for line in data_str.split("\n"):
    row = line.split()
    data.append(row)

# ######## this is the code required to process sql output
import collections
date_map = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for date, met, val in data:
    date_map[date][met] = val

rows = []
for date, data in date_map.iteritems():
    row = [date]
    rows.append(row)
    values = data.items()
    values.sort()
    row.extend((v for met, v in values))
    print row
```

output:

```
['2012-10-19', '66.4952', '66.8063', '47.4484', '56.0447']
['2012-10-18', '63.3617', '53.3617', '43.3617', '65.0656']
['2012-10-17', '67.3747', '55.3472', '66.2868', '66.4952']
['2012-10-16', '65.7312', '67.3116', '65.9559', '65.0656']
```

Comment: I should have specified - I want the information to end up stored in the same table in my SQL database (without having to drop it and re-create it). Thanks though - this brings almost there!

Comment: @Mike that is very unusual requirement, you are totally changing the Table, better to do it by dropping and recreate, why you would want it anyway?

Comment: the table is very large, and its only going to get bigger. I have not shown it, but there are lots of other columns as well. It would be inefficient to drop it.

Comment: @Mike it will more inefficient to drop columns and rows at will, this looks a very bad design, there must be better ways to do this e.g. who is writing to that table, why can't you put it in separate table at same time?